# With statement not working

Tags: vb.net, with-statement

Why doesn't this work?

```
Module Module1

Sub Main()
    With System.Console 'error BC30691: 'Console' is a type in 'System' and cannot be used as an expression.
        .WriteLine("here a text!")
        .ReadKey(True)
    End With
End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: You could give us more information, we're not clairvoyant! Please tell us what error you are getting, and what results you think you should be getting, and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WriteLine and ReadKey are `Shared` methods, you do not have an instance to use with the `With`

You need to instantiate a variable in order to use it with `With`

Answer (score 4):

MSDN for [`With`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx) says:

> **objectExpression** *Required*. An expression that evaluates to an object. The expression may be arbitrarily complex and is evaluated only once. The expression can evaluate to any data type, including elementary types.

This means that `With` is used for instance methods (and properties) however `WriteLine` and `ReadKey` are static (or [`Shared`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx)) methods and `System.Console` is a type, not an instance of an object. This is why you can't use `With` in this case.